# How to get value from radiobutton to linkbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, radio-button

I'm trying to get the value of radio button selection to my listbox, but the listbox always gets the same value even though selection was different. Please help, I am a newbie to coding, I couldn't find any answers on the net either..

Here are the codes I've written:

```
void rdbtnOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (rdbtnOne.Checked == true)
  {
     rdbtnOne.Text = "Men";
  }
  else
  {
    rdbtnOne.Text = "Women";
  }
}

void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lstOne.Items.Add(i +  rdbtnOne.Text);
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution, FINALLY. The reason that my code did not work in the first place was because I tried to give value by equaling rdbtnOne.Text directly. Instead I created another value to equal it. All right here is how it worked for me:

```
  string MenOrWomen;
  void rdbtnTwo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbtnTwo.Checked.Equals(true))
        {
            MenOrWomen = "Women";
        }
        else
        {
            MenOrWomen = "Men";
        }
    }

    void rdbtnOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbtnOne.Checked.Equals(true))
        {
            MenOrWomen = "Men";
        }
        else
        {
            MenOrWomen = "Women";
        }
    }
    int i = 1;
    void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstOne.Items.Add(i + MenOrWomen);
        i++;

    }
```